# How to plot both results in different figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which called kyc_df. Below is the screen shot of the df after export in excel.

[image: Image of DF exported in excel]

These are my codes to to generate the results into a plot. First chart is horizontal bar and 2nd chart is normal bar.

```
kyc_df[(kyc_df['result_report'] == "consider") & (kyc_df['image_integrity_result'] == "consider")]['issuing_country'].value_counts()[:20].plot(kind='barh');

kyc_df[(kyc_df['result_report'] == "consider") & (kyc_df['image_integrity_result'] == "consider")]['nationality'].value_counts()[:20].plot(kind='bar');
```

The end result displays both charts in one figure. Able to guide me how to get them into 2 separate chart window? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Use `subplot` to plot multiple image once.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the key point. Added in fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2) and update the exising code to display in different axes. It works...      
kyc_df[(kyc_df['result_report'] == "consider") & (kyc_df['image_integrity_result'] == "consider")]['issuing_country'].value_counts()[:20].plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[0,0], title="Test1");